# ansible when how to check is text exist

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, yaml

How can I write this code into ansible(yaml) format?

```
grep -i "^\s*PermitRootLogin\s* no\s*" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
if [ $? -eq "0" ]
then
 echo "[ PASSED ] - Ensure SSH root login is disabled" 
else
  echo "[ FAILED ] - Ensure SSH root login is disabled"
fi
```

This is what I have, I don't know what to write in the when

```
- name: Check permitRootLogin
  hosts: web
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        state: absent
        regexp: '^\s*PermitRootLogin\s* yes\s*'
      check_mode: yes
      register: permit

    - name: Ensure SSH root
      debug: 
        msg: 
         - "[ PASSED ] - Ensure SSH root login is disabled"
      when: $regexp == 'PermitRootLogin yes'
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Just want to mention that the code you posted, would not work anyway, due to the error in the regexp.

Comment: Can you point out the error please

Comment: You are telling grep to use simple regular expressions, but `\s`  is just a 2-character string to be matched literally. If you would use for instance `-P`, you would tell grep to use PCRE instead of simple ones, and `\s` would be interpreted as white space. BTW, a asterisk at the end of a regexp is redundnant, and \s* would **always** match at the end. Therefore you can simply drop it. Finally `\s* ` is equivalent to `\s+` in PCRE, so your regexp can be simplified to `^\s*PermitRootLogin\s+no`.

Comment: BTW, if you are only interested in the success of grep, and don't need to see the whole matched line, it would make sense to use `-q` as well.

Comment: Related [question #73537131](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73537131/ansible-playbook-based-on-condition-increase-count-print-message-and-append-t)

Answer (score 1):

Ansible is commonly used to create a desired state. But you can do the trick and use `check_mode: yes` as you already tried, not to actually write back the change, but only to simulate it. For this, however, you must write a fully functional task.

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    state: present
    line: "\\g<1>yes"
    regexp: '^#?(PermitRootLogin\s+)'
    backrefs: yes
  check_mode: yes
  register: permit_root_login_result

- debug:
    msg: "[ PASSED ] - Ensure SSH root login is disabled"
  when: permit_root_login_result is not changed
```

In this case you simulate the change of the line `PermitRootLogin` to the value `yes`. If this change has taken place, the option was not set to `yes` before.

If you want to switch the output between `PASSED` and `FAILED`, your `debug` task could look like this:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "[ {{ permit_root_login_result is changed | ternary('FAILED', 'PASSED') }} ] - Ensure SSH root login is disabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always debug by printing out the output of the register:

```yaml
- name: Print result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ permit }}"
```

Every module in Ansible has a different output.
When you get the output/depending on your use case, you can then choose which attribute to use in your condition:

```yaml
TASK [Print pass/fail result] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "backup": "",
        "changed": false,
        "diff": [
            {
                "after": "",
                "after_header": "/etc/ssh/sshd_config (content)",
                "before": "",
                "before_header": "/etc/ssh/sshd_config (content)"
            },
            {
                "after_header": "/etc/ssh/sshd_config (file attributes)",
                "before_header": "/etc/ssh/sshd_config (file attributes)"
            }
        ],
        "failed": false,
        "found": 0,
        "msg": ""
    }
}
```

In your case, you want to know if the line `PermitRootLogin yes` is found.
So you can use the attribute `found` from the output:

```yaml
- name: Ensure SSH root login is disabled
  debug: 
    msg: 
     - "[ PASSED ] - Ensure SSH root login is disabled"
  when: permit.found == 0

- name: Ensure SSH root login is enabled
  debug: 
    msg: 
     - "[ PASSED ] - Ensure SSH root login is enabled"
  when: permit.found != 0
```

Comment: I don't understand this line "When you get the output, you can then choose what to use as a condition:"

Comment: @usertest5522 Every module in Ansible has a different output. For the lineinfile module, it depends if the searched line is found. Like the other answer, the `changed` attribute was used. Other modules could even have many attributes in the output, which can be used in conditions.